# Wait for chained observables to complete

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs5, angular2-observables

Having some trouble achieving what I want with RxJS5 - I have a simple Observables chain, started with Rx.Observable.interval:

```
const Rx = require('rxjs');

var i = 0;

const obs = Rx.Observable.interval(100)
    .flatMap(function () {
        return Rx.Observable.timer(Math.ceil(500*Math.random()))
            .map(function(val){
                console.log(' => These should all log first => ', val);
                return i++;
            });
    })
    .take(5)
    .merge()  // this doesn't seem to do what I want to do
    .map(function (val) {
        console.log('all done = > ', val);
    });

obs.subscribe();
```

The above logs this:

```
 => These should all log first =>  0
all done = >  0
 => These should all log first =>  0
all done = >  1
 => These should all log first =>  0
all done = >  2
 => These should all log first =>  0
all done = >  3
 => These should all log first =>  0
all done = >  4
```

I am looking to log this:

```
 => These should all log first =>  0
 => These should all log first =>  0
 => These should all log first =>  0
 => These should all log first =>  0
 => These should all log first =>  0

all done = >  [0,1,2,3,4]
```

It's clear that we are not waiting for all the timer observables to finish, as you will see "all done!" logged many times, interspersed with "These should all log first".

How can I get the output I am looking for?

Normally, we could use `zip` for this, but the API for `zip` does not fit this use case, because we don't have all the timer observables in one place at the same time!

If my question was not clear enough, here is the analog of what I want to do, we block on all callbacks until we arbitrarily finish and we have collected all the results:

```
const async = require('async');
var i = 0;

async.forever(function(cb){

    process.nextTick(function(){
       console.log('These should all log first');
       const err = i++ === 5;
       cb(err, i);
    });

}, function done(err, results){
    // let's pretend results contains all the i values
    console.log('all done');
});
```

Comment: note that if we substitute takeLast() for merge(), we will log "all done" after all of "These should all log first" which is "correct", but then "all done" is logged 50x! I want "all done" to be logged only once :)

Comment: `take` doesn't batch them up, it just ends the stream when it's seen enough. And `merge` on a single stream doesn't do anything at all. Have a look at e.g. http://rxmarbles.com/#merge which provides nice illustrations of what's happening.

Comment: Hmm, wouldn't you expect "all done" to log as many times as there are elements, since you are mapping them? Based on this code I would actually expect to see that map console log trigger as many times as you "take". I think your use of merge is probably not doing what you expect, because you're not feeding merge what you think you are (it doesn't just sit there and wait for all your "taken" objects, then merge them all at once).

Comment: is the question somehow unclear ? :) I don't know how to do this and there must be a better way to do it than the preliminary answer I just posted. Note that is just a simple example and I need a good solution for my use case which can be distilled to this example question (I think)... take(50).something() should be able to merge all returned observables into one somehow, but what is something()?

Comment: Do what? What should the output be? It might be easier to show with 5 than 50! Give some context around what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Sure, I can change it to 5.

Comment: all I want is for the timer observables to all  run, but there to only be "one final callback" after all the previous observables have run.

Comment: I don't think the question is unclear. I think we're trying to tell you why what you have isn't working and giving you some things to examine. If you can create a running sample somewhere you'd probably get a rewrite faster. (50, 5 or 500 shouldn't matter, I think we get that all you want to see is that once trace).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132563/discussion-between-tim-consolazio-and-alexander-mills).

Answer (score 0):

Note that this basically yields the logging order that I was expecting to see, but I don't think this is the right/best way to do it:

```
   const {Observable} = require('rxjs');

    const obs = Observable.interval(100)
        .flatMap(function () {
          return Observable.timer(Math.ceil(500*Math.random()))
              .map(function(val){
                  console.log(' => These should all log first => ', val);
              });
        })
        .take(5)
        .takeLast()  // <<<<<<<<<<
        .map(function () {
            console.log('all done');
        })
        .take(1)    // <<<<<<<<<<

   obs.subscribe();
```

I think there is yet a better way to achieve this.

Comment: You could replace everything between `take(50)` and `subscribe` with `last(function() { console.log('all done'); })`, or just move that log into the complete callback on the subscription.

Comment: Replace `flatMap` with `concatMap` (unless it doesn't matter in which order your randomised timers complete and return value), replace `takeLast` with `toArray` and remove `take(1)`

Answer (score 0):

@jonsharpe gave me this answer, which basically works. The problem can really be distilled down to just `Rx.Observable.interval`, we can get rid of the `Rx.Observable.timer` mapping. Here's our basic answer:

```
const Rx = require('rxjs');

const obs = Rx.Observable.interval(100)
    .take(5)
    .map(function(v){
        console.log(v);
        return v;
    })
    .reduce(function (prev, curr) {
        return prev.concat(curr);
    },[])
    .last(function (results) {
        return results;
    })
    .map(function(v){
        console.log(v);
    });


obs.subscribe();
```

I would be very interested, however, in a way to do this *without* reduce.

Comment: `reduce` is necessary to collect all values into array. Although I don't see why you need `last`, reduce produces single result anyway. It is also semantically better to invoke `all done` in `subscribe` instead of `map` with empty `subscribe`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe you may be right, but that goes against the semantics of reduce doesn't it :)

Comment: Even if this isn't what the OP wants, and like you say the semantics of "reduce" and "last" is interesting, this is an interesting piece of code. I captured it to assist my evolving understanding of Rx.

Comment: @AlexanderMills sorry, turns out I was thinking of [`scan`](http://rxmarbles.com/#scan); `scan` -> `last` is the equivalent of `reduce`

Comment: Oh, this answer *is* what the OP wants, but I am really looking for a way to do this without reduce, there must be a way!

Comment: @jonrsharpe ah so what you are saying is scan is an alternative to reduce...will check it out

Comment: @AlexanderMills no, I'm saying `scan` is what you'd use if you wanted the intermediate results (for example, if you didn't know if the source stream would *ever* end and wanted the partial sum so far as it emits each item). You only want the final result, so `reduce` is the correct version. You could either use `scan(...).last(...)` **or** `reduce(...)`, and the latter is clearly neater.

Answer (score 0):

So the requirement is:

- Let the top level interval run N times.
- Each interval should return an array of Y timer observables.
- Next should trace out N times, each time with an array of Y observables.

This does that. It's a little naive, but it does work.

```
    let timerArrLength = [ 4, 2, 3 ];
    let svc = Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
        .take(timerArrLength.length)
        .map(function ( index ) {
            let arr = [];
            for ( let i = 0; i < timerArrLength [ index ]; i++ ) {
                arr.push ( Rx.Observable.timer ( 1000 ) );
            }
            return arr;
        });


        svc.subscribe(
            function onNext(v){
                console.log('=> v =>',v);
            },
            function onError(e){
                console.error(e);
            },
            function onComplete(){
                console.log('complete');
            }
        );
```

Comment: let me test this out :)

Comment: Note I removed the first let var, you don't need it, just use the length of the array.

Comment: hey Tim, what I get logged out is a bunch of observables, see if you can get all the values to be unwrapped in one final callback. For distillation purposes, just get rid of the timer and just use interval.

Comment: take a look at the updated answer that I updated that was from jon

Comment: Right, based on the requirements as stated though I thought that's what you were looking for (wasn't sure why but that's what you seemed to ask for). I'll see what I can do, time for coffee though. Maybe you can use this as a starting point. I think using .concat() and .last() with the code I have here might do the trick.

Comment: yeah I am trying to work with this - what would be really neat is to merge all the observables into one observable AND THEN unwrap the result. That's why/how I think we could do it without reduce somehow...

Comment: If we concat those arrays into one array, grab the last one (which would be the total array), and return observable.from (theLastArr), that would do it I think.

Comment: Yeah, that might work, but I am wondering if that is in the spirit of the original question - the original question assumes we have observables but that the observables are not created at the same time or place. In your map function you are creating all those timer observables in the same place / same tick of the event loop. One of my criteria (at least I tried to make it known) is that the observables are not necessarily created at the same time/place, which is what interval was for.

Comment: Sorry I am not trying to switch it up on you, I asked the original question with a lot of unknowns, and I am not very good with RxJS yet if that wasn't obvious :)

Comment: NP my own understanding is evolving as well (btw I tried to move this to chat twice, the boterator is unhappy with all these comments). I get that my solution introduces some naïveté, but in my old age I tend to start with what gets me the end result I want then try to figure out the elegance in time.

Comment: I have to hit the hay, but if I come up with something good on this I will ping you, feel free to do the same, thanks

Comment: note that if you have multiple observables in the same place/time you can just use zip to do what I want to do, but my original question is all about how to do zip but if you don't have the observables in the same tick/place.

Comment: I actually looked at zip. It didn't seem to get me what I wanted in your more-or-less original source. And I think to "zip" you need them all at the same time, otherwise something like reduce or concat/last would seem to be the prescribed way.

Comment: maybe this? http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/observables/BlockingObservable.html